# How to clear the Laravel Application Key via Terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, laravel

I'm creating a application. I want to clear the Laravel Application key via terminal. Not manually.

Is there any way to clear via artisan. I can only generate via following command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

But there is no option to delete the key via artisan command.

Comment: They made it to make apps on the fly, not delete them on the fly. You're going to have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way as I of right now I believe, but if you use git just fork laravel, go ahead and empty the application key and whenever starting a new Laravel project clone from your repo and just generate a key without editing anything.

I see that you're using Ubuntu, but just so you know there is a OSX extension for Alfred for creating Laravel projects [here](https://github.com/clarkeash/Laravel-Alfred-Extension) and comes with Jeffrey Way's Generator.